# How to get all selected checkbox details upon clicking Apply button

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I have 3 components s360_ListingFilter,s360_multiselectcheckbox and s360_inlinecheckbox.

Here Iam passing  mypicklist value to s360_multiselectcheckbox . Then I have pass to s360_inlinecheckbox.

How can I display like this(Img1). How can i get all checked box details upon clicking apply button. Can you suggest any idea contest of current code

s360_ListingFilter

```
   <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="S360_ListingsFilterController" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<aura:attribute name="options" type="Object[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="options1" type="Object[]"/>
<aura:attribute name="category" type="string[]"/>
 <c:S360_MultiSelectCheckboxComponent CompId="CategoryId" picklistValues="
 {!v.options}"  GroupLabel="Category"/>
<c:S360_MultiSelectCheckboxComponent CompId="LanguageId" picklistValues="{!v.options1}" GroupLabel="Language"/>  </aura:component>
```

---

```
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
    var opts=[];
    var action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");
    action.setParams({
        objectAPI:'asb_App__c',
        fieldName:'Categories__c'
    });

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state=response.getState();
        // alert('state'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        if(state=='SUCCESS'){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            //component.set("v.AppTable",response.getReturnValue());
            for(var i=0;i<response.getReturnValue().length;i++){                                       
                opts.push({ value:response.getReturnValue()[i], label: response.getReturnValue()[i]});              
            }
            component.set('v.options', opts);
            helper.languageMethod(component);
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
```

### }

```
     ({
      languageMethod : function(component, event, helper) {
      var opts=[];
     var action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");
      action.setParams({
        objectAPI:'asb_App__c',
        fieldName:'Languages__c'
    });

action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state=response.getState();
        // alert('state'+JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        if(state=='SUCCESS'){
            //alert(JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
            //component.set("v.AppTable",response.getReturnValue());
            for(var i=0;i<response.getReturnValue().length;i++){                                       
                opts.push({ value:response.getReturnValue()[i], label: response.getReturnValue()[i]});              
            }
            component.set('v.options1', opts);    
        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);        
}
```

})

---

```
  public class S360_ListingsFilterController {
@AuraEnabled
public static List<String> getPicklistValues(String objectAPI,string fieldName){

    Map<string,String> mapReturn = new Map<string,String>();

    Schema.SObjectType targetType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get(objectAPI);
    Sobject Object_name  = targetType.newSObject();
    Schema.sObjectType sobject_type = Object_name.getSObjectType(); //grab the sobject that was passed
    Schema.DescribeSObjectResult sobject_describe = sobject_type.getDescribe(); //describe the sobject
    Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldmap = sobject_describe.fields.getMap();

    List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldNames = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

    // for (String fieldName : fieldMap.keySet()){
    list<string> options=new List<string>();
    List <string> options1 = new List<string>();
    Schema.DisplayType fielddataType = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getType();

    if(fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.Picklist ||fielddataType == Schema.DisplayType.MultiPicklist) {
        List<Schema.PicklistEntry> pick_list_values = fieldMap.get(fieldName).getDescribe().getPickListValues(); 
        String str = String.valueOf(fieldMap.get(fieldName));
        String values='';
        for (Schema.PicklistEntry a : pick_list_values) { 
            values = values + a.getValue()+'|'+a.getLabel()+',';
            options1.add(a.getValue()+'|'+a.getLabel());  //It contains value and name label
            options.add(a.getLabel());//Here added only Label to the List
        }

        values = values.subString(0,values.length()-1);

        //mapReturn.put(str,options1);
        mapReturn.put(str,values);

    }
    // }
    System.debug('mapReturn'+mapReturn);
    return options;
}
//Passing Filters values here
@AuraEnabled
public static string FilterPassing(string filterVal){
    system.debug('@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@'+filterVal);

   string query='WHERE asb_App__r.Categories__c includes (\'Apps\')';

        return query; 
}
```

}

---

s360_multiselectcheckbox

```
<aura:registerEvent name="OnChange" type="c:OnChange" />

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
<!-- handler clicked checkbox -->
<aura:handler name="OnClick" event="c:OnClick" action="{!c.handleOnClick}"/>

<!--Event Handler-->
<aura:handler event="c:NotifyPicklistCmp" action="{!c.handleNotify}" />

<!-- define methods -->
<aura:method name="invalidatePicklist" action="{!c.methodHandleNotify}" access="public" 
             description="method to invalidate picklist comp"/>
<aura:method name="getDefaultValue" action="{!c.methodHandleGetDefaultValue}" access="public"/>

<div class="{!v.IsHidden ? 'slds-hide slds-is-relative' : 'slds-show slds-form-element slds-is-relative'}">
    <legend class="slds-form-element__legend slds-form-element__label">
        <abbr class="{!v.IsRequired ? 'slds-required slds-show' : 'slds-hide'}" title="required">*</abbr>
        {!v.GroupLabel}
    </legend>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <aura:iteration items="{!v.picklistValues}" var="item">

            <c:S360_CheckboxInline CompId="{!v.CompId+'#'+item.label}" InputLabel="{!item.label}" IsChecked="{!item.isChecked}" IsDisabled="{!v.IsDisabled}"/>

        </aura:iteration>
    </div>

</div>
```

S360_checkboxInline

```
<!-- additional event registration -->
<aura:registerEvent name="OnClick" type="c:OnClick" />
<aura:registerEvent name="simple" type="c:simpleEvent"/>


<div class="slds-form-element__control">
    <!--ui:inputCheckbox click="{!c.onClick}" value="{!v.IsChecked}" class="slds-input"/-->
    <span class="slds-checkbox">

        <abbr class="{!v.IsRequired ? 'slds-show slds-required' : 'slds-hide'}" title="required">*</abbr>

        <p> checked value:{!v.IsChecked}</p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="options" id="{!v.CompId}" checked="{!v.IsChecked}" disabled="{!v.IsDisabled}" 
               onclick="{!c.onClick}" aura:id="checkbox" class="{!v.InputClass}"/>



        <label class="slds-checkbox__label" for="{!v.CompId}">  
            <span class="slds-checkbox--faux"></span>
            <!--span class="slds-form-element__label"> {!v.InputLabel}</span-->
        </label>

        <label class="{!(v.InputLabel == '' ? 'slds-hide slds-is-relative' : 'slds-form-element__label')}" for="{!v.CompId}">
            <abbr class="{! 'slds-required ' + (v.IsRequired ? 'slds-show' : 'slds-hide')}" title="required">*</abbr>
            {!v.InputLabel}   
        </label>

    </span>
</div>
```

```
      ({
      onClick : function(component, event, helper) {

    var labelvalue=component.get("v.InputLabel");
    alert('label value @@@'+labelvalue);
    //var checkedvalue=component.find("v.IsChecked");
    //alert('checkedvalue>>>>>>>>>>'+checkedvalue);

    var evt = $A.get("e.c:simpleEvent");
    evt.setParams({
        "InputLabel": labelvalue
    });
    evt.fire();


 component.set('v.IsChecked', !component.get('v.IsChecked'));
    var event = component.getEvent('OnClick');
    event.setParams({
        "CompId": component.get('v.CompId'),
        "payload": component.get('v.IsChecked')
    });
    event.fire();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can approach this by multiple ways

- Using an `ui:inputCheckbox` and binding an `aura:attribute` to the value parameter of the checkbox. When someone click on the button you can change the boolean value to true and this would select all the checkboxes.
- Using an `aura:Id` to get all components by the same name. Iterate and assign the values to true. It would do the same thing mentioned above.

But these above-mentioned methods are cumbersome to maintain and are probbaly not the best way to approach this requirement.

Hence Salesforce introduced **`"lightning:checkboxGroup"`** through which you can do a select all or select multiple checkboxes easily. This is one of the cleanest approaches that i have come across so far.

> **Component :**

```
<aura:component access="global">
    <aura:attribute name="selected" type="List" default="[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[{'label': 'Ross', 'value': 'option1'}, {'label': 'Rachel', 'value': 'option2'},{'label': 'Olivia', 'value': 'option3'}]"/>
    <lightning:checkboxGroup
        aura:id="mygroup"
        name="checkboxGroup"
        label="Checkbox Group"
        options="{!v.options}"
        value="{!v.selected}"
        onchange="{!c.handleChange}"
        required="true" />

    <br/><br/>
    <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Select All" onclick="{!c.selectAll}"/> 
</aura:component>
```

> **Controller.js**

```
({
    selectAll : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.selected",['option1','option2','option3']);
    },

    handleChange : function(component, event, helper) {

    },
})
```

> **Output**

**Before :**

[image: Before Select]

**After :**

[image: After Select]

Just an FYI - the component  should be more than or equal to 41.0

Comment: Can you please answer the question for that current context of code.Instead of general,it will very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

## Component:

### 1.) Creat List for store dynamic value of checkbox-

```
   <aura:attribute type="List" name="selectedCheckBoxes"/>
```

### 2.) Dynamic checkboxes from list (Iteration)-

```
  <aura:iteration items="{! v.productlist }" var="prod" aura:id="product1">
     <lightning:input aura:id="{!prod.Id}" type="checkbox" value="{!prod.Id}" 
     label=" {!prod.Name}" onchange="{!c.selectedproduct}" checked=""/>
  </aura:iteration>
```

## 3.) for select/unselect checkbox selectedproduct JS is call

```
selectedproduct : function(component, event, helper) {
    var capturedCheckboxName = event.getSource().get("v.value");
    var selectedCheckBoxes =  component.get("v.selectedCheckBoxes");
    var len=selectedCheckBoxes.length;
    var addval=0;
    for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
        if(selectedCheckBoxes[i]==capturedCheckboxName){
            selectedCheckBoxes.splice(selectedCheckBoxes.indexOf(i), 1);
            addval++;
        }
    }
    if(addval==0){
        selectedCheckBoxes.push(capturedCheckboxName);
    }
},
```